# RayCastAll from Camera to Player Not Working

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics

Trying to run a raycast from my camera to Z = 0 that will hit objects on the TransparentFX layer and temporarily make them transparent as they are likely blocking the view of the player.  But the raycast never hits anything.

Camera
https://i.stack.imgur.com/no130.jpg

Tree
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM2nh.jpg

ClearSight.cs

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class ClearSight : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private LayerMask raycastLayers;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 10;
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, forward, Color.green);
        RaycastHit2D[] hits = Physics2D.RaycastAll(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), 10f, raycastLayers);
        if(hits != null && hits.Length > 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Found objects blocking player!");
            foreach(RaycastHit2D hit in hits)
            {
                Debug.Log("Making " + hit.transform.gameObject.name + " transparent!");
                AutoTransparent at = hit.transform.GetComponent<AutoTransparent>();
                if(at == null)
                {
                    at = hit.transform.gameObject.AddComponent<AutoTransparent>();
                }

                at.MakeTransparent();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AutoTransparent.cs

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer))]
public class AutoTransparent : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private SpriteRenderer[] renderTargets;
    [SerializeField]
    private float transparentRecoveryTime = 0.1f;

    private bool isTransparent = false;
    private float transparencyTimer = 0;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isTransparent)
        {
            UpdateTransparencyTimer();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateTransparencyTimer()
    {
        transparencyTimer += Time.deltaTime / transparentRecoveryTime;
        if(transparencyTimer >= 1)
        {
            MakeOpaque();
        }
    }

    public void MakeTransparent()
    {
        transparencyTimer = 0;
        if (!isTransparent)
        {
            isTransparent = true;
            foreach (SpriteRenderer renderer in renderTargets)
            {
                Color c = renderer.color;
                renderer.color = new Color(c.r, c.g, c.b, 0.3f);
            }
        }
    }

    public void MakeOpaque()
    {
        isTransparent = false;
        foreach(SpriteRenderer renderer in renderTargets)
        {
            Color c = renderer.color;
            renderer.color = new Color(c.r, c.g, c.b, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I was using RaycastHit2D and Physics2D.RaycastAll, which uses Vector2 parameters so the Z forward variable was being taken out of the equation.  Switched up to Box Collider and Physics.RaycastAll and it works great.